# CSS3 Flex Box - Div overflows when it wraps

Tags: css, overflow, flexbox, word-wrap

I'm trying to make a responsive design for a web app, but I'm running into problems with the divs not resizing when it wraps. I'm trying to avoid javascript for styling if at all possible.

I have a wrapper div with flex-flow:column wrap;. The divs inside have a minimum width so when the screen gets too short, it will wrap into a row. The problem is that if the second div is full horizontally, it doesn't resize horizontally when it wraps.

This is an example of my problem:

HTML:

```
<div id=wrapper>
    <div id=header>
        Header<br />
        Resize the black box to see the issue.
    </div>
    <div id=middle>
        <div id=middle-left>Middle Left</div>
        <div id=middle-right>Middle-ish from a more vertical point of view but definitely more to the right side, though only if it's not too tall, then it's more of a middle-low vertically.</div>
    </div>
    <div id=bottom>Bottom</div>
</div>
```

CSS3:

```
#wrapper {
    border:2px solid;
    padding:10px 40px;
    width:500px;
    height:600px;
    resize:vertical;
    overflow:auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
#header, #middle, #bottom {
    border:1px solid red;
}
#middle-left, #middle-right {
    border:1px solid blue;
    min-height:100px;
    flex:1;
}
#middle-left {
     min-width:200px;   
}

#header {
    flex: 3 1;
}
#middle {
    flex:3;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:column wrap;
}
#bottom {
    flex:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spencer4of6/m474n/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. I ended up using CSS media queries with max-widths and max-heights. It's kind of a hackish way to do things, but nothing else seemed to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `overflow` property on the parent container to avoid this issue:

```
#middle {
overflow: hidden;
}
```